# Returning Uploadifive Ajax 'Error/Success' data from Codeigniter Controller

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter, uploadify

I'm using the [Uploadifive](http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/) upload plug-in. It works as it should. However, I'm having a hard time passing `error` and `success` messages from my controller back to my view via the plug-in. I'm logging console and `log` errors. But can't seem to return any controller errors back to the Uploadifive call to display in my view.

In short, I want to output either an `error` or `success` message from my controller (via the `$result` var) back to my ajax function to embed into my view.

The alert, `alert(data.result)` outputs "undefined".

JS function:

```
$('#file-upload').uploadifive({                 
    ...

    'onUpload': function(file) {
        console.log('upload complete!');
    },
    'onUploadComplete' : function(file, data) {
        console.log('The file ' + file.name + ' uploaded successfully.');

        // returned error/success message here
        alert(data.result);

    },
    'onError': function(errorType) {
        console.log(errorType);
    }
});
```

CI Controller method:

```
function add_document() {

    // If Ajax request, proceed:
    if(isset($_POST['is_ajax'])) {

        if (!$this->upload->do_upload()) {
            
            // If file upload failed or is invalid, 
            // display error notification
            $result = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
            echo json_encode($result);
        }       
        else {
            
            // If file upload was successful
            $result = 'success!';
            echo $result;

            ...
        }
    }
    // if not, redirect to upload page
    else {
        redirect('upload');
    }

}
```

Comment: What are you getting in your console?

Comment: Just the `console.log` as detailed in the js (which is fine). No other errors. The alert though (`alert(data.result);`) outputs "undefined".

Comment: Ok console.log data and file in your upload complete function, I'm going to get a coffee then we will smash this.

Comment: Once I got my head around **Uploadifive** vs **Uploadify**, I hit the wall with the fact that this script is not free and their documentation is horrible (contains nothing about the server responses) - am going to need some more console debugging from your end I think.

Comment: Yeah, you can imagine my frustration as well lol. Not sure what other debugging I can run...if you need to uploadifive src, email me via email on profile. I have no problem sending you the "paid" version. :D

Comment: Just `console.log` `file` and `data`, that should give you an idea of what's going on between your controller and AJAX.

Comment: Looking at your other post, success in the default packaged demo controller code is `echo 1` (boolean) - have you tried that?

Comment: To speak on your first comment, when I log `console.log(data);` in the complete, console outputs: `{"error":"<p>The filetype you are attempting to upload is not allowed.<\/p>"}`. So I think I'm in the right direction...

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to get this to work with my controller code. Uploadifive is not well documented, so it's been a shaky ride. But none the less, here's how I got it to function the way I wanted. Hopefully this helps others.

***In my controller,*** I replaced the `echo json_encode($result);` line with the below. Specifying the array key I want to use (i.e. error) and the outputting of the result as `html`.

```
echo html_entity_decode($result['error']);
```

***In my javascript function,*** all I simply needed to do was output the `data`... `.result` was not needed in the alert. Note, I decided to attach the result to some `html` versus an alert.

```
// Display Error/Success Messages
$('.status').html(data);
```